# how to import a class in code splitting using import()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, code-splitting, transloadit

I cannot find out how to import a class in my React app after using the code splitting.

**Before (it works!):**

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import Tus from './components/test';

 class Shopper extends PureComponent {
    constructor (props) {
    super(props); }

  uploadModal () { 

/* some function code... */

   .use(Tus, { 
        endpoint: 'http://192.168.22.124:3000/upload/'
    })
  /* more codes... */ 
 }
```

**After using code splitting (does not work):**

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';

 class Shopper extends PureComponent {   
    constructor (props) {
    super(props); }

  uploadModal () { 

/* some function code... */

   .use(import('./components/test').then(Tus => Tus, { 
        endpoint: 'http://192.168.22.124:3000/upload/'
    })
  /* more codes... */ 
 }
```

I am getting this error after using code split

> TypeError: Expected a plugin class, but got object. Please verify that
>   the plugin was imported and spelled correctly.

When I console.log

```
import('./component/test').then(Tus => console.log(Tus))
```

I get this:

```
ƒ Tus(uppy, opts) {
    _classCallCheck(this, Tus);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Plugin.call(this, uppy, opts));

    _this.type = 'uploader';
    _this.id = 'Tus';
    _this.titl…
```

Comment: What is `.use()`? Does it take a promise as an argument? Also, don't pass your "endpoint" object as an argument to `then`.

Comment: @Bergi https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#uppy-use-plugin-opts

Comment: I made it work by doing: 
 `.then(useTus => {
        return import('uppy/lib/plugins/Tus')
        .then(data => useTus.use(data, {
          endpoint: 'http://192.168.22.124:3000/upload/',
          headers: { 'Authorization': this.props.token }
        })) })`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that on your working example (before code split), you're importing the default export from `'./components/test'.

After you dynamically `import` to allow code-splitting, you should use `Tus.default` to achieve the same result. You can read more about it on [webpack code splitting documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports).

In other words, `import('./component/test').then(Tus => Tus.default)`

I hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Tus.default did not work...

`.use(import('./components/test')
        .then(Tus => Tus.default, { 
        endpoint: 'http://192.168.22.124:3000/upload/'
         }))`

Comment: Hmm, maybe the problem lies with the `uploadModal` function, since it seems it doesn't support asynchronous code. One way to test this hypothesis is declaring it as `async uploadModal() {}` and at the beginning declare `const { default: Tus } = await import('./component/test')`, then use the code of your first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can aslo use [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) it provides you loading component fallback:

```
function Loading() {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

const Test= Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./components/test'),
  loading: Loading,
});
```

In your route:

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={Test} />
```

You should have installed:
in your `package.json`:

```
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.0.0-beta.54",
```

in .babelrc

```
"plugins": [
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",]
```

It works great.